# Swiftui + Core Location: Map fails to center on user

Tags: swiftui, location, mapkit, core-location

I want to build a view with a map centered on the user location when loaded. I managed to build this, but **sometimes** the map loads with latitude 0, longitude: 0. This happens when I move too fast between views (there are other views in the project besides the map).

It feels like the user location is loaded too slow and the Map appears with default coordinates, but I really have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Map view:

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapView: View {
    @StateObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
    @State var trackingMode: MapUserTrackingMode = .follow


    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $locationManager.region, interactionModes: .all, showsUserLocation: true, userTrackingMode: $trackingMode)
    }
}
```

Location View Model:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion()
    private let manager = CLLocationManager()
    override init() {
        super.init()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        locations.last.map {
            let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: $0.coordinate.latitude, longitude: $0.coordinate.longitude)
            let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2)
            region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: span)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is exactly your problem. Location data will ALWAYS lag, just like any other retrieved data. What you need to consider is a mechanism to update your views when you get updates.

The best way to do that is to `import Combine` in your `LocationManager` class and use a `PassthroughSubject` like this:

```
let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
@Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion() {
    willSet { objectWillChange.send() }
}
```

That allows you to subscribe to your publisher in the map and get updates. You will find many tutorials regarding this.

Comment: thank you for the tip! It led me down a pretty deep rabbit hole about asynchronous queues and whatnot. I really tried to understand Codable but in the end I implemented a solution from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_srswdKouk. It is not very elegant in that once location is loaded, the tracking is stopped (otherwise location updates keep snapping the map back to the user location). But that is a separate issue

Comment: Keep working on it. It gets easier. That being said, Combine can be tough to get into.